# Once off connection to MySQL in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Is there a way that allows me to connect to a `mysql` server/database, once, in `netbeans`, throughout the duration of a program instead of having to connect every single time a query needs to be executed?

Comment: create separate class for MySQL database Connection then create instance of your Connection class where you need MySQL connection.

Comment: Use a [*connection pool*](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: @Omore - makes sense

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I'll google more on connection pools.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can create connection pool or use another implementation. The connection pool should be singleton and to initialize at startup of application.